# For any integer $N$, can you find an odd prime $p$ such that $(p^2-1)/4$ is coprime to $N$?

Tags: number-theory

For any integer $N$, can you find an odd prime $p$ such that $\frac{p^2-1}{4}$ is coprime to $N$?

This is equivalent to asking: Does there exist a prime $q$ which divides $\frac{p^2-1}{4}$ for every odd prime $p$?

Comment: Yes, q = 2.  Bu I assume you mean q is odd and p > 3.

Comment: Which is to say p^2 - 1/4 is never a power of 2.  Which... it never is unless p =3.

Comment: As 24 divides p^2 - 1 for all p >= 5, maybe you meant (p^2 - 1)/24?
Then for example 7 => 2, 11 =>5, 13 => 7 and 17 => 12=3*4, the first composite number  and ... um, now I lost track what the question was supposed to be.  N to not have a coprime generated N must be a product of all the primes and prime factors generated requiring only a finite number of primes and prime factors generated. Is this the case?  I doubt it but I doubt I can prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not if $N$ happens to be even.

Comment: Oh god damnit you're right. What's the larger framework for this? This isn't really a question about quadratic residues, it's not really CRT...

Comment: And if N is odd p = 3 will always work.

Comment: And if $N$ is odd and divisible by $3$, $p=3$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{p^2 - 1}{4} = \frac{p-1}{2}\frac{p + 1}{2} $ is always even. So if N is even, no.

$\frac{3^2 - 1}{4} = 2$.  So f N is odd, yes.